# ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/aldryn_newsblog/article/add/

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, django-cms

[Here are the files in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5ECk.png)

Trying to follow the tutorial for integrating Django CMS into an existing application, Im also using cookiecutter. (the "project" is my homework)

After installing aldryn-newsblog I have been stuck on the following error for quite some time (everything is working normally until I try and use the aldryn plugin to create a new article, that's when the error pops up.) :

ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/aldryn_newsblog/article/add/

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/aldryn_newsblog/article/add/
ImportError my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig: No module named 'my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig'; 'my_awesome_project.users.apps' is not a package
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/aldryn_newsblog/article/add/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    
ImportError my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig: No module named 'my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig'; 'my_awesome_project.users.apps' is not a package
```

Here is my backlog :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/aldryn_newsblog/article/add/

Django Version: 2.1.5
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'djangocms_admin_style',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'cms',
 'menus',
 'treebeard',
 'sekizai',
 'filer',
 'easy_thumbnails',
 'mptt',
 'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
 'djangocms_link',
 'djangocms_file',
 'djangocms_picture',
 'djangocms_video',
 'djangocms_googlemap',
 'djangocms_snippet',
 'djangocms_style',
 'djangocms_column',
 'polls',
 'polls_cms_integration',
 'aldryn_apphooks_config',
 'aldryn_boilerplates',
 'aldryn_categories',
 'aldryn_common',
 'aldryn_newsblog',
 'aldryn_people',
 'parler',
 'sortedm2m',
 'taggit',
 'crispy_forms',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'rest_framework',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
 'cms.middleware.utils.ApphookReloadMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback:

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/aldryn_newsblog/article/add/
Exception Value: ImportError my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig: No module named 'my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig'; 'my_awesome_project.users.apps' is not a package
```

Running :

```
django-cms                    3.6.0  
Django                        2.1.5 
alabaster                     0.7.12   
aldryn-apphooks-config        0.5.2    
aldryn-boilerplates           0.8.0    
aldryn-categories             1.2.0    
aldryn-common                 1.0.5    
aldryn-newsblog               2.2.1    
aldryn-people                 2.2.0    
aldryn-translation-tools      0.3.0
```

I tried including 
     'my_awesome_project.users.apps.UsersConfig',

on the top of the list, with no luck.

Any help appreciatted !

Comment: What is `apps.UserConfig`? it doesn't seem to be an application.

Comment: It was the default name of my project app, im using django cookiecutter.
Also, everything is working normally until I try and use the aldryn plugin to create a new article, that's when the error pops up.

If I just put the app name, i get the error :

    LookupError: Model 'users.User' not registered.

Comment: The line in `INSTALLED_APPS` should probably be `'users.apps.UsersConfig',`. We can’t tell for sure unless you show the layout of the files and directories in your project.

Comment: Heya, tried that aswell, with no luck. I included the link for the image of my files at the original post :)